# Arrow Function not working for an onClick event handler

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use arrow function as I have on the first button's (aBtn1) onclick event handler?
Can someone please explain why the first approach fails?

```
<script>
    var arrFunc = () => {
        console.log('test btn clicked');
    };
</script>
<form>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="name" />
    <input type="button" name="aBtn1" value="Test" onclick="() => { console.log('test button clicked'); }" />
    <input type="button" name="aBtn2" value="Test" onclick="arrFunc();" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Your first listener defines an arrow function expression but never calls it. It's akin to writing `onclick="arrFunc;"`.

Comment: How about just `<input type="button" name="aBtn1" value="Test" onclick="console.log('test button clicked');" />` without the arrow function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first option only declares a function w/o calling it. You need to call it after the declaration. `(() => { console.log('test button clicked'); })()` which makes little sense you could simply use the body of the function.

```js
var arrFunc = () => {
  console.log('test btn clicked');
};
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="name" />
  <input type="button" name="aBtn1" value="Test" onclick="(() => { console.log('test button clicked'); })()" />
  <input type="button" name="aBtn2" value="Test" onclick="arrFunc();" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of an `onclick` attribute is the body of a function.

You have created a function which defines an arrow function.

You never call that function. You never assign that function to a variable. You never do anything with that function.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I removed the curly braces and the semicolon from aBtn1

This is what I end up with for aBtn1:
`<input type="button" name="aBtn1" value="Test" onclick="(() => console.log('test button clicked'))()" />`

Comment: could not reproduce your approach, removeing curly braces and semicolon, i.e.  onclick="() => console.log('test button clicked')" or did I get it wrong ?